# How to remove blank spaces from drop downs in Excel? Ignore Blank checkbox doesn't work

Tags: excel, validation

I am creating drop-downs using list data validation in Excel.

I am checking the **"Ignore Blank"** checkbox *ON* while creating the drop-down. Yet, the blank spaces are not being ignored and it shows in the drop-down.

Also, the number of blank spaces is equal to the number of rows in column A (in given Example). In case of multiple columns,

*The number of blank spaces = Total number of rows in longest column - Number of values in selected column for drop-down*

Also, usage of UNIQUE function in data validation is showing error.

How do I solve these issues? I am submitting screenshots for reference.

[Selecting Data validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGeax.png)

[Blank Spaces showing in drop-down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga6YX.png)

[Unique Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3uZV.png)

Comment: I would use a dynamic range reference -- either a table with a structured reference address; or a Named range using the INDEX function, so as to not have all those empty rows at the end.